# Titling a Json Dictionary in alamofire Request?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

Simple query, i am building a request struct to serlaise params into json.

It seems to work, apart from I need to create the 'parent' key for the request and im not sure how?

So far I have this:

```
struct UserRequest {

let long: String
let lat: String
let dist: String

init(long: String, lat: String, dist: String) {
    self.long = long
    self.lat = lat
    self.dist = dist
}

func converToParameters() -> [String : String] {
    return [ "lat": long,
             "lng": lat,
            "distance": dist
    ]
}
```

}

but i want my request to conform to this serialisation

```
    {
"near": {
    "lat": "",
    "lng": "",
    "distance": ""
} }
```

my question is how do i get that 'near' parent title into my serialisation? Im sure its simple but I havent had to bundle my request in this manner before

Comment: Unrelated but you can delete the `init` method. In a struct you get the *memberwise initializer* for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the return type to `[String : Any]` for that.

```
func converToParameters() -> [String : Any] {
    return ["near" : [ "lat": long,
             "lng": lat,
             "distance": dist
    ]]
}
```

Comment: thanks, how do i get the extra curly braces around the request too as they are needed

Comment: `[String : Any]` is already a dictionary which means curly braces in json.

Comment: thats odd as the request fails from my app but in postman its successful, the only difference is the braces

Comment: @jwarris91 Please don't mix up JSON (`[], {} and :`) and Swift collection type (`(), {} and =`) string representation.